# Restart a animation in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to start an animation in an interval, and when I am clicking on a button which moves my div to another position, finishes the animation and clears the interval

```
function startInterval(){
    Interval = setInterval(function(){
        moveIndicator();
    }, 50);
}

function stopInterval(){
    clearInterval(Interval);
}

function moveIndicator(){
    Pos += Dist * SpeedRatio;
    if(Pos >= W){
        Pos = W;
       stopInterval();
    }

    Animation = $("#Cursor").animate({ 
        left: Pos + "px",
    }, 49);
}

function goToNextEvent(){
    var Target = $("#Cursor").css("left");
    Target = parseInt(Target, 10);
    var PTarget = (Target / W) * 100;

    Animation.finish();

    $("#Cursor").css("left", Positions[NbCurrentEvent] + "%");
    Pos = $("#Cursor").css("left");
}
```

I am calling *stopInterval* just before *goToNextEvent* which is working, but when I am calling *startInterval* again, the cursor is not moving anymore, even if *moveIndicator* is called, I have checked it with logs.

What could be problematic here ?

Comment: There is too much code missing to give a correct answer but could it be, that the stopInterval() in moveIndicator ist always directly stopping the timer because once W is reached it will stoppp always on condition Pos >= W

Comment: Thanks for your answer, W is not reached with the goToNextEvent() call but it could have been a problem.
Actually I found what was wrong, in the goToNextEvent() function, I was setting Pos to the left value of the div, which was given in pixels. I had to add a parseInt to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the *goToNextEvent* function.

```
Pos = $("#Cursor").css("left");
```

was returning a value in pixels like 150px, so when *moveIndicator* was called, `Pos += Dist * SpeedRatio;` became a string concatenation, instead of an addition.

The solution is to replace the *Pos* line by

```
Pos = parseInt($("#Cursor").css("left"), 10);
```